# The Data Flows Down in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi Im just learning react
I've small problem

I want to learn how to pass state data to its Child as props

Here's me code

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Clock from "./Clock";
import Test from "./Test";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Clock />,
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Clock.js

```
import React from "react";
import Test from "./Test";


class Clock extends React.Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
  };

 

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
 
  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date(),
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
        <h3> Time Now</h3>
       <Test date={this.state.date} />
           </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Clock;
```

Here's the Child component I want to pass the state I named it test

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

I got this error >>

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleTimeString' of undefined
date undefined although I gave its parent props

```
Please I need help
thanks in advanced
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are seeing the error because of `Test` Instance used in `App.js`. You are not passing in data over there. Removing it from there may get rid of error.

**App.js**

```
import Clock from "./Clock";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Clock />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've passed props perfectly in `Clock.js` however in `App.js` you are not passing `date` as a prop to `<Test />` which is why you're getting the above error.